# How can I limit the number of attempted login by user, then display a message and block user for 3 minutes in PHP

Tags: php

Below is my PHP code and I want to store them in a session and reset after 3 minutes.

So when the user has had 3 wrong tries it displays "you have had too many tries" my main problem is how do I block the user for 3 minutes after displaying the message?

```
<?php
    class user{
        /// User Login
        public function logIn($user,$password){
            $counter =0;
            $counter++;
            $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","animal"); 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= '$user' AND password='$password'";
            $result =  $con->query($sql);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            $name = $result->fetch_row();
            if($count===1){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $name[0];
                $_SESSION['password'] = $name[1];
                $_SESSION['counter']=$name[2];
                Header ("Location:home.php");
                return true;
            }
            else{
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['counter']++;
                if($_SESSION['counter'] >2){echo 'you have had too Many wrong tries';}
            }
        }
        //counter
        public function counter(){
            $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","animal");
            $find_counts = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users");
            while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($find_counts)){
                $current_counts = $row['visits'];
                $new_count = $current_counts + 1;
                $update_count = mysqli_query("UPDATE `animal`. `users` SET `visits`= $new_count");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is not good: sql injection, plain-text passwords and on top of that you store it in the session as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120328/how-to-limit-the-number-of-login-attempts-in-a-login-script

Comment: 3 **minutes** OR 3 **times**? Getting confused in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a session variable to check the number of unsuccessful login attempts and then block the user from logging in by setting a timer for three minutes. This method is based on the current session of the user and is not very reliable.
You can also save the number of unsuccessful login attempts for that IP address in the database and also save the time of unsuccessful login. Later you can let the user login if he logs in after three minutes.